# MSSQL -- Create View with PK

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, view

My create view code like this

```
create VIEW [dbo].[vw_test]
AS
SELECT     'B' AS rtype, ID FROM TB_A
UNION ALL
SELECT     'V' AS rtype, ID FROM TB_B
GO
```

How to create a PK with. I need to do full-text search.
Tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you could create a unique clustered index on a view, but not an actual primary key constraint. [Article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187864.aspx).

However, the [SQL in the view contains a UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) so you can't do this.

Comment: Thanks. My answer added nothing to the discussion so deleted.